# recommended way to implement request-password-reset in Loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

To implement password reset request in loopback (send email to the user with reset link), we need to [handle the event `resetPasswordRequest`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Logging-in-users.html).

This is a possible implementation below

```
Client.on('resetPasswordRequest', function(info) {
  var options = {
    type: 'email',
    to: info.email,
    from: '....',
    ...
  };

  Client.email.send(options, function(err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
});
```

With this approach, if an error occurs it is simply logged to the console. Throwing an error that won't be handled doesn't feel like a better solution either.

Why is it not mentioned in the docs to use an `afterRemoteHook` to add this logic or even create a new custom endpoint ? Both solutions seem better at handling errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is based on [example application](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management#how-do-you-perform-a-password-reset-for-a-registered-user), isn't it? If so, this approach is used by developer of example application but is not required implementation. You may use any other appropriate solution and one is that what you've mentioned in your question.

As for emitting event - it has it's advantage. You emit event and immediately send response to request. So client app will not wait until email sending part will send email - this can take from seconds to tens of seconds.

You may implement email sending log and make another request to it while user is waiting for password reset email thus notify him if any error will occur.

From the other hand this is only example but not required implementation for using in production.

Comment: Oh right, I did not realize that sending emails using SMTP might be so long. In that case it makes sense. If you can comment on how to handle errors with the event handling approach, I'll accept your answer

Comment: Could you please clarify your question about handling errors? Do you mean 'low-level' error handling inside event handler? In this case you may use custom error handling with middleware as usual. Or do you mean processing errors at business logics level? In such case I think event handler is a kind of microservice so one need to implement required handling depending of it usage. Sorry, if I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Well my idea was to send back this error to loopback so that it goes through loopback's error handler instead of just being a log to the console. This part may be too vague to answer here, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: In my answer I've mentioned email sending log and I meant not a kind of console log but some subsystem. E.g. you may implement model EmailLog and: a) create instance during request processing with unique `id` and status `'sending'` and then change status for this `id` to `'sent'` or `'error'` inside event handler depending on status returned by mailer. Or you may simply expand your custom `User` model with `changePasswordRequestEmailStatus` or so. And thank you for accepting my answer.